# Best way to handle graphics on iPhone game

Tags: iphone, graphics, image, opengl-es

I will be writing a game and a friend will be doing all the graphics.

What is the best way to handle the graphics in the game?

We dont want to draw things, we will have all the images done before the time.

Which is the best way to have these images displayed?

I have read and looked at tutorials on opengl es and see that they are all teaching how to draw things from scratch almost.

Which direction can you point me in if I would have all my images and graphics pre-drawn?

Is it a bad approach to have like a cartoon animation style, where all the images are drawn and then displayed appropriately during game play?

These will still need to be done fast and multiple times.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the amount of graphics and frame-per-second you want. If you are looking at OpenGL, I highly recommend you take a look at what [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) [can do](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/GamesUsingCocos2d)...

If response time is not a concern (e.g. board games), [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is great for its simplicity.

Comment: I will take another look at cocos2D , but the game will need fast graphics changes to change the character whenever a move is made.

Comment: Is this not seen as a private API in apples perception?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is I dont know what is the amount of graphics considered OpenGL ES acceptable.

Is there a reference or an explanation on this topic?

Surely I dont need to do custom graphics if I have all the art work done before hand?